# Git status summary

Tags: git, git-status

I added recursively files and folder under a folder in git and would like to know the summary (say x files, y folders). I didn't find a suitable parameter for git status. Do we have a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

[git ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) would help. Check the options to get modified files etc. Also git doesn't deal with folders at all only with files in subfolders, so you have to write some scripting wrappers for your particular case

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), status summary information is shown in Powershell by default.

[image: posh-git status summary]